# Java Datagram Socket.recieve() freeze

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

While using datagram sockets in java for a game, a very weird issue appears. I'm trying to recieve a packet on the client but nothing happens. This is not what's weird however. I have set a timeout for the socket directly in front of the socket.receive() call and it still never times out.

What's even more odd is that the implementation seems to be working completely at random. Sometimes it works like a charm and a steady package exchange stream appears between the server and the client. In this case, I can see my friend walking around and he can see me as well. Sometimes however, the client completely freezes in the socket.recieve().

The server and client are run on separate threads and only handle network communications.

Basically, the issue is that the client socket.receive() seems to freeze and never time out. Any ideas of what might be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

The Client run() method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while(running) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                System.out.println("BEFORE RECEIVE");
                socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
                socket.receive(packet);
                System.out.println("AFTER RECEIVE");
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                 if(!disconnected){
                     System.out.println("TIMEOUT, RESENDING");
                     sendData(loginPacket.getData());
                 }
                // e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
        }
    }finally {
        System.out.println("SOCKET CLOSED");
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The server run() method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(10);
        while(running) {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);
            }catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                continue;
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("REcieve Packet: " + new String(packet.getData()));
            parsePacket(packet.getData(), packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
        }
    }catch (SocketException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got nuthin'.  Mebbe validate the socket in the "BEFORE RECEIVE" in case something occasionally corrupts or overwrites it, (not sure how to do that)?

Comment: 10 millisecond sis absurdly short for socket timeout. It's less than the granularity of the Windows clock for example. Use a second or more.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 

I'll try that Martin.

EJP, The 10 millisecond timeout isn't an issue so far though. The server is working fine. Forgot to mention that only the client socket freezes.

Comment: Is it the client's GUI freezing?